# How can i clone from git app without occurred no error

Tags: android, git

I want to clone this app from git

https://github.com/mdy0501/Airbnb

But there is a problem when I clone it from git

When I clone its layout show 'Unresolved class'

!-- This is one of layout that shows error --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/DeepGreen"
    tools:context="com.android.airbnb.WelcomeActivity">
```

**Under this code shows red**

```
@color/DeepGreen
.airbnb.WelcomeActivity
```

Even though that .xml and class file has existed
That showing error (i attach photo also) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeivE.png)

I want to know how I can fix that
when I clone from git that 
I would be very thankful if I see that activity from my android studio

Comment: it has nothing to do with cloning. It is cloned correctly. Either the repository has mistakes, or you just need to build the project first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those red lines came from android studio not being able to find them. Make sure they are all available and the path is as expected like the WelcomeActivity. Make sure the package name is as expected and the build.gradle has the constraint layout dependency. If you have done those, all you do is sync, clean and rebuild your app. All the errors will go away.